# New to OpenMP and parallel programming need to partition a loop using scheduling

Tags: visual-c++, parallel-processing, openmp

Ok so here's what the problem says.
Implement a simple loop that calls a function containing a delay. Partition this loop across four threads using static, dynamic and guided scheduling. Measure execution times for each type of scheduling with respect to both the size of the loop and the size of the delay.

this is what I've done so far, I have no idea if I'm on the right track

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    double start_time, run_time;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);

    start_time = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel 
#pragma omp for schedule(static)

    for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++){
        printf("square of %d=%d\n", n, n*n);
        printf("cube of %d=%d\n", n, n*n*n);
        int ID = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Thread(%d) \n", ID);
    }

    run_time = omp_get_wtime() - start_time;
    printf("Time Elapsed (%f)", run_time);
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you need a loop, where the distribution makes a difference. The loop has 100 iterations, so the OpenMP schedule will only 100 times decide what is the next iteration for a thread what takes no mensurable time. The output with printf takes very long so in your code it makes no difference which schedule is used. Its better to make a loop without console output and a very high loop count like

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for schedule(static) private(value)
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        value = ...
    }
}
```

At last you have to write code in the loop which "result" is used after the loop with a printf for example. If not the body could be deleted by the compiler because of optimize the code (it is not used later so its not needed). You can concentrate the time measurings on the parallel pool without the output of the results.

If your iterations nearly takes the same time, then a static distribution should be faster. If they differ very much the dynamic and guided schedules should dominate your measurings.